# Better way for making an array for Connect 4?

Tags: c

I am having more trouble with these array as it seems I have limited understanding on building and utilizing an array. How should I pass a specific cell to an array? In this example I am trying to pass the chip value of a specific column that occupies row 8. How would you manipulate the value of a 2D array cell based on the location of the cell as shown below?

Below is the link to a compiler I have been using online, I also used a minimalist portion of the code to illustrate my overall goal. I am trying to push the
https://onlinegdb.com/mB1kiOtOBM

```
int row;
int col;
int array [row][col];
int const chip = 1;

while(left == 1)
{
  row = 8;
  for(int col = 8; 8 > col > 0; col ++)
   {
     chip = array [row][col];
   }
}
```

Comment: Begin by not using a word-processing program, but instead a proper text-editor, which doesn't capitalize lines and "sentences". Not even for short simple examples. A proper [mre] would be nice for us to have.

Comment: Perhaps you are having difficulty because you are not using the optimal data structure for the job? Maybe instead of an array, you used a several queues? (Which might look very much like arrays, but you have an extra piece of information, top.) And also, an `enum` would make it more clear.

Comment: The line `for(int col = 8; 8 > col > 0; col ++)` is very very wrong. What is it supposed to do? iterate for `col` from `8` to `1` inclusive?

Comment: @tstanisl What is wrong about it?

Comment: @tstanisl it is supposed to increment the column by shifting the bit to the left

Answer (score 0):

> How should I pass a specific cell to an array? In this example I am trying to pass the chip value of a specific column that occupies row 8.

If I'm understanding your question correctly, in this case the verb you want is *assign* instead of *pass*.
We usually say pass a thing to another when it comes to function calls. Say you define your function `foo(int x)` and you call it `foo(2)`. You're passing the value `2` to the function.

So if you're trying to change one value in the array, you want something like `array[7][0] = chip`. This sets the first cell of 8th row to whatever value that `chip` holds. Note that arrays are 0-indexed in C.

Comment: For a second I thought that array[7] [0] = chip; would create a 1D 7 row array. If you set a 2D array equal to something it just gets the location at the first cell in the 8th row?

Comment: If I return this from a loop, can I return multiple iterations for each time?

Comment: @RyanPaye Creating an array will require a declaration, meaning you have to do something like `int myArray[2][2];` You can check this page for more details: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_arrays.htm. As of return, it will end the function, and give back the value you're returning to the caller. I'm not sure what you mean by return multiple iterations for each time. If you mean to return each time you're in the loop for multiple times, then the answer is no. The `return` will only be executed only once and the function will end.

Comment: That's good to hear, but I have a nested loop outside of the function. I am returning it once each iteration of the nested loop. So I have a while loop where I hold my array and returning, and outside of that loop I have a big for loop that repeats 64 times.